# Logical OR in Microsoft Academic Graph with JSON syntax

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, academic-graph

I'm trying to run a search on Microsoft Academic Graph using a logical OR condition. Specifically, I want to use OR to specify two different possible values for some field, such as two possible author names in the author field.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/jsonsearchsyntax) on the JSON search syntax suggests that the logical OR operator can be used, I just can't figure out how to implement it.

I've tried to implement this using the following search:

```
{
"path": "/paper/AuthorIDs/author",
  "paper": {
    "type": "Paper",
    "NormalizedTitle": "graph engine",
    "select": ["OriginalTitle", "PublishDate", "CitationCount", "AuthorIDs", "JournalID", "DOI"]
  },
  "author": {
    "select": ["Name"],
    "return": {
      "type": "Author",
      "or":{
        "Name": "bin shao",
        "Name": "haixun wang"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it just returns results from the second author. Any help on how to properly format my search would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the API, the `expr` field should be formed like this:

`Or(Composite(AA.AuN='{AUTHOR-NAME-1}'), Composite(AA.AuN='{AUTHOR-NAME-2}'))`

Example:

```
https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?&expr=Or(Composite(AA.AuN=%27bin%20shao%27),%20Composite(AA.AuN=%27haixun%20wang%27))&count=10&attributes=AA.AuN,AA.AuId,DOI,Ti,VFN,Y&orderby=Y:desc&subscription-key={YOUR-KEY}
```